# The video only works on YouTube (Firefox)

Tags: firefox

In the firefox, videos work well only on YouTube and in advertisements before videos on other sites. The videos themselves on other sites are slowing down. The problem is only in this browser, everything is fine in chrome

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your machine does not have the full range of video codecs in place. This may resolve your issue:

1. Open Terminal
2. Install `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   sudo apt install ffmpeg
   ```

   No restart is necessary.

Chrome uses its own internal codec package, so this issue isn’t seen as often.